# Is there a specific way to capture a part of your screen with QuickTime Player?

Tags: quicktime

When I open up QuickTime Player to record, where do I find the option to record a part of the screen? I have checked the little down arrow, nothing. I've been trying to find a way but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Recording a selected part of your screen is very easy.

1. Open *Quicktime* (if you get a *Finder* window, select `Done`)
2. Select `File -> New Screen Recording`
3. Click the *Record* button on the small popup window
4. You'll see a screen overlay message like this:
   [image]
5. Drag the cursor around the part of the screen to record
6. Click *Stop* to end the recording.